# What are these arguments in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Usually i'm programming in PHP, i started learning javascript few days ago and i really don't understand functions with arguments like "from the air".

Usually in PHP you are passing arguments to function and it is processing in function's body. Can some one explain me on this example what the 'ev' or 'event' is ?

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

What i get till now that 'event' and 'ev' are the same, but where 'event' came from ? It's not declared anywhere...

Comment: I don't see any difference between JS and PHP (or indeed any other mainstream language) here. They're formal parameters to the function, and don't need to be defined outside. They take the value of whatever is passed in when the function is called. [In this case they are event listeners so the parameter is likely to be an Event object,]

Answer (score -1):

```
 The web browser defines many events of different kinds. Each
 definition includes, as the data structure passed to the handler
 function, an object which inherits from the EventPrototype object.
```

You can check below url for more information event objects.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Overview_of_Events_and_Handlers
```